# How can I set an icon for my custom mimetype

Tags: android

I have created a new mimetype, it works very well with file browser, and it open my activity, but it displayed as unknown icon on file browser, I use ASTRO file browser.
I have added an icon for the intent, but it still appears as unknown icon
this is my code

```
    <activity android:name=".SharedActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="swv">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="swv">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.swv" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="swv">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/swv" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="swv">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.swv" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the icon on the `<activity>` element, instead of (or in addition to) on the `<intent-filter>` elements.

Comment: I have tried it, no result, the icon of swv file is still display as unknown icon, Any another idea???

Comment: @Gavohab: Ask the folk at ASTRO what they use for the icon. You can also put the icon on `<application>`, but you probably already have that.